# Hackerank "Find the Factor" (in javascript) is failing because of time limit?

Tags: javascript, algorithm

I had to find all the factors of positive number that evenly divide into a number and then return a `p^th` element of the list, sorted ascending.
If there is no `p^th return 0.`

I tested almost all the answers i could solve and found online:

Example:

```
function pthFactor(n, k) {
let arr = [];
for (let i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
    if (n % i === 0) {
        arr.push(i);
    }
    if (arr.length === k) {
        return arr[arr.length - 1];
    }
}
if (arr.length !== k) {
    return 1;
}
};
```

or

```
var kthFactor = function(n, k) {
let factors = [1]
for(let i=2;i<=Math.floor(n/2);i++){
    if(n%i == 0) factors.push(i)
}
factors.push(n)

return factors.length < k?-1:factors[k-1]
};
```

buts its failing  10 sec time limit.

What i am doing wrong ?

By the way i also tried `Math.sqrt` etc in order not to loop `n` times. Didn't work as well.
Do i need to know more than for loop ? Like dynamic programming etc to solve this ?

Comment: Could you share the link to the problem?

Comment: @Uriah, you should really react to comments made here...

Comment: Hi, Sorry. I solved the question. I don't have a link to question. Error was i had to sort an array

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find this challenge on HackerRank, but the [1492. The kth Factor of n](https://leetcode.com/problems/the-kth-factor-of-n/) challenge on LeetCode seems to be the same as you describe:

> Given two positive integers `n` and `k`.
>
> A factor of an integer `n` is defined as an integer `i` where `n % i == 0`.
>
> Consider a list of all factors of `n` sorted in **ascending order**, return *the* `kth` *factor* in this list or return **-1** if `n` has less than `k` factors.

It is strange that you used the name `pthFactor` in your first code block, while the name of the relevant argument is `k` and not `p`. That is quite confusing.

> I also tried `Math.sqrt` etc in order not to loop `n` times

You cannot only consider factors up to the square root of . For instance, 6 is a factor of 12, and even 12 is a factor of 12.

However, about **half** of all factors are in the range up to the square root. And those factors that are greater, are equal to the quotients found by performing the divisions with those smaller factors. So in the end, you *can* stop at the square root, provided that you collect all those quotients, and pick the right one from those if you didn't arrive at the <sup>th</sup> factor yet.

So here is how that idea could be implemented:

```js
 var kthFactor = function(n, k) {
    let bigFactors = [];
    let quotient = n + 1;
    for (let factor = 1; factor < quotient; factor++) {
        if (n % factor === 0) {
            quotient = n / factor;
            k--;
            if (k <= 0) return factor;
            if (factor >= quotient) break;
            bigFactors.push(quotient);
        }
    }
    return bigFactors[bigFactors.length - k] ?? -1;
};

// A few test cases:
console.log(kthFactor(12, 3)); // 3
console.log(kthFactor(7, 2)); // 7
console.log(kthFactor(16, 5)); // 16
console.log(kthFactor(27, 5)); // -1
console.log(kthFactor(927, 1)); // 1
```

Comment: Question asked in interview. So it may not be visible in hackerrank.

Answer (score 0):

This code uses the same algorithm as in [trincot's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68430496/1243641), but I think it's expressed more simply with recursion:

```js
const kthFactor = (n, k, f = 1, r = []) => 
  f * f > n
    ? r [k - 1] ?? -1
  : n % f == 0
    ? k == 1 ? f : kthFactor (n, k - 1, f + 1, f * f == n ? r : [n / f, ...r]) 
  : kthFactor (n, k, f + 1, r)


console .log (kthFactor (12, 3));  //=> 3
console .log (kthFactor (7, 2));   //=> 7
console .log (kthFactor (16, 5));  //=> 16
console .log (kthFactor (27, 5));  //=> -1
console .log (kthFactor (927, 1)); //=> 1
```

Here we track the factor we're testing (`f`) and the remaining numbers (`r`) to be tested, decreasing `k` whenever we find a new factor and adding the quotient `n / f` to our remaining numbers, increasing `f` on every step, stopping when we've gotten too big (`f * f > n`) and then finding the index in the ordered list of remaining numbers, returning the factor when `k` is `1`, and simply recurring with an incremented factor otherwise.

The only tricky bit is the handling of perfect squares, where the square root should only be counted once, so we don't prepend it to the remaining numbers if `f * f == n`.

Because of the recursion, this is only suitable for a `k` so large.  While we could make this tail recursive in a simple manner, it doesn't matter much as of this writing, since tail call optimization has *still* not happened in most engines.